# Cordova phonegap on eclipse/ Android

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to install a sencha touch 2.0 project into Android emulator using Phonegap (cordova).

I followed the steps mentioned in the tutorials and tried HelloWorld example and it works!

I put my project in www directory under assests folder , the cordova jar file, xml folder is added also

In the main class I did the following:
`super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");`

But after running the application, it show the following in the console :

```
[2012-06-11 15:48:27 - PhoneGap] Uploading PhoneGap.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-06-11 15:36:13 - PhoneGap] Uploading PhoneGap.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-06-11 15:38:10 - PhoneGap] Installing PhoneGap.apk...
[2012-06-11 15:38:12 - PhoneGap] Installation failed due to invalid APK file!
[2012-06-11 15:38:12 - PhoneGap] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2012-06-11 15:38:13 - PhoneGap] Launch canceled!
```

The logcat:

```
06-11 13:00:27.003: DEBUG/SntpClient(65): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-11 13:04:24.309: DEBUG/dalvikvm(141): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1K, 12% free 14374K/16327K, paused 11ms+5ms
06-11 13:05:27.041: DEBUG/SntpClient(65): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
06-11 13:06:05.003: INFO/installd(34): free_cache(6710880) avail 4059136
06-11 13:06:05.009: ERROR/installd(34): cannot open /data/secure/data/: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.341: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.349: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.349: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.370: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.370: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.370: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.370: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.401: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.431: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.431: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.453: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.453: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.453: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.453: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.459: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.473: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.479: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.479: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.479: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.479: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.479: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.479: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.479: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.502: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.519: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.529: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.529: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.529: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.529: ERROR/installd(34): Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
06-11 13:06:05.539: WARN/PackageManager(65): Couldn't clear application caches
06-11 13:06:05.539: INFO/DeviceStorageMonitorService(65): Running low on memory. Sending notification
06-11 13:06:05.871: DEBUG/Tablet/NotificationPanel(266): notificationCount=1
06-11 13:06:06.123: INFO/dalvikvm(266): Jit: resizing JitTable from 512 to 1024
06-11 13:06:06.209: WARN/ActivityManager(65): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.intent.action.MAIL_SERVICE_CANCEL cmp=com.android.email/.service.MailService }: not found
06-11 13:06:12.769: DEBUG/dalvikvm(286): GC_EXPLICIT freed 67K, 9% free 6420K/6983K, paused 4ms+10ms
```

Do I have to update my index.html file to include cordova.js file ??

Comment: `Please check logcat output for more details.`

Comment: Hell yeah... Include the cordova.js file in your index.html

Comment: I included it , the same problem

    <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="sdk/microloader/development.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.0.js"></script>

Comment: do i have to do something else (I'm beginner)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse to create native android applications then its really simple to run sencha application in your android emulator.

i can show u some simple steps of doing it.

1)I would suggest you to use MDS applaud phone gap http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/34483744/PhoneGap%20Eclipse%20PlugIn%20for%20Android to install phonegap .

2)As soon as u complete the installation u will see the phone gap icon at the top.

3)then click on it to create a minimal phone gap project.

4)u will then see the index file with non necessary things. u can replace the index file as below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>The Sencha Touch List Component</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css">

   <script type="text/javascript" src="touch/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
   Ext.Loader.setConfig({
   enabled: true,
   paths: { 'Ext': 'touch/src' }
   });
  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
  </html>
```

5)If you want to use phone gap features u can include phonegap.js also.then in the assets folder u can create the folders necessary to create a sencha application.like the app folder,the styles folder,the touch folder and the other necessary things like the css files and the app.'s inside the www folder.

6)U can check the configuration is correct or not by just checking out the index.html file in the web browser in eclipse only.

7)if its ok ,then u can run the application in ur android emulator,the same way as u do for ur native apps.